# Selecting MAX value error

Tags: mysql, max

This is my code for selecting the max JO_NO:

```
strQ = "SELECT MAX(JO_NO) + 1 from js_hdr"

    cmd = New MySqlCommand(strQ, con)
    Try
        con.Open()
        rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While rs.Read

           txtJO.Text = IIf(Not IsDBNull(rs.Item("JO_NO")), rs.Item("JO_NO"), 0)

        End While
        rs.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        con.Close()
    End Try
```

The error in this code is: **Could not find specified column in results: JO_NO**

I have checked my table and there is the column JO_NO.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not set any alias for the computed column that's why it can't find the column.

```
strQ = "SELECT MAX(JO_NO) + 1 AS JO_NO from js_hdr"
```

if you want to set the value to zero using query if there is no record yet, you can use `COALESCE`

```
strQ = "SELECT COALESCE(MAX(JO_NO), 0) + 1 AS JO_NO from js_hdr"
// other codes 
txtJO.Text = rs.Item("JO_NO")
```